# What is this User Agent Stylesheet code means?

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

I've been looking and analysing User Agent Stylesheet. What does the following mean ?

[image: Sample Screenshot]

Comment: User Agent Stylesheet means the stylesheet which were added by the browser ( in which user is checking the page ) itself

Answer (score 0):

...its the line number of the code you are viewing.  In most browsers if you click on it, the line will be highlighted in the dev tools menu making it extremely easy to find where your html is being stylized by your CSS.  The same occurs with JS errors allowing you to find where the error occurred. This can also be seen in editors, IDEs, etc.

Comment: Also worth noting is that this convention isn't specific to browser developer tools - you'll find the same in use in a number of IDEs for a variety of platforms besides web.